# Using jQuery trigger for click event on parent window element by class name

Tags: jquery, click

I am using

```
$(".abc",window.opener.document).trigger('click')
```

To trigger click event on parent window element.

But it is not working.An element exist in the parent window with class name `abc`.

How i can trigger onclick event ?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
window.opener.$('.abc').trigger('click')
```

Comment: do you have jQuery in the child window? do you get any javascript error?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **context-parameter**

```
$(".abc",parent.document)
```

But if you really use a **popup**, you need to access **opener** instead of **parent**

```
$(".abc",opener.document)
```