# Trigger event on parent page hidden field from a child page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421386/using-jquery-trigger-for-click-event-on-parent-window-element-by-class-name), but the solution provided there is not working for me, so I am posting a question similar to this.

I have a parent page which has a hidden field like below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reloadCalPreview" id="reloadCalPreview" value="0" runat="server" />
```

Then I have trigger created in `$(document).ready(function(){}}...` as below:

```
$("#reloadCalPreview").on('reload-change', function () {
  console.log('reload-change event triggered.');
  var reloadCalPreview = $("#reloadCalPreview").val();
  if (reloadCalPreview == "1") {
    GetUserCalPreview();
    $("#reloadCalPreview").val("0");
  }
});
```

So this is supposed to trigger once a change occurs to the hidden field.

Then there are two scenarios for me:

1. hidden field value gets changed from the parent page
2. hidden field value gets changed from the child page

For scenario 1, I am using the below code to trigger the `reload-calendar` event:

```
function appAdded(){
  $("#resetCalendarRequired").val("1").trigger("reload-change");
}
```

Which as expected triggers the `reload-change` event.

So for scenario 2, in the child page there is a function call like this:

```
function manageEvent() {
  var reloadCalPreview = $("#reloadCalPreview", window.parent.document);
  reloadCalPreview.val("1").trigger("reload-change");
}
```

But this doesn't trigger the reload-change.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
function manageEvent() {
    var reloadCalPreview = window.parent.document.getElementById('reloadCalPreview');

    // debug purpose, to make sure that the element is accessible
    console.log("reloadCalPreview: " + reloadCalPreview);

    // invoking the event
    $(reloadCalPreview).val("1").trigger("reload-change");
}
```

Comment: yes i have the element is accessible but the trigger is not happening